# My created webdriver script gives a exception when execute using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Im very new to selenium and tried creating a test script in eclipse. When the class is executed using TestNG a testngexception is thrown. can some one please check whether there is a issue with the script I have written?

```
package first_package;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test_Class_Automation {

    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.lk");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using testng annotation then you don't need to write main method there. You can just write it in this way:
package first_package;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test_Class_Automation {

    @Test
    public void testCase {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.lk");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks but now it doesn't  identify it as a class. noclassfoundexception is given.

Comment: I would suggest start from scratch,  in ur package right click and create a new testng class which would ask to select annotations and then write the above method and execute it as testng class.

Comment: Run this class and as TestNg class not as java